# No module named pymc3

Tags: pip, pymc3

HI i'm trying to import pymc3 after pip installing it from the command line within the library where Python.exe sits in. (i.e. >>python -m pip install pymc3). after checking the Lib/Site-Packages library, there's no pymc3, but there is a theanos package installed though. i've looked everywhere for the pymc3 package but can't find it. i've tried installing pymc4 and same thing happens. any idea why?

Comment: Try to use `pip3`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run pip straight for command line.
IE: the command is "pip install pymc3"
Then you would need to import it.
Your issue might also be that you recently installed python and have pip3 installed and not pip. You can check if pip vs pip3 is installed with pip --version and pip3 --version.
Whichever one of those responds with some form of pip XX.X.X from /.... would be the command you need to run.
If you do have pip3 then the command to run from the command line would be "pip3 install pymc3"

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to do

```
import pymc3
```

in a Python script? If so, you can find out where it's installed with

```
print(pymc3.__file__)
```